# Rigging a multi-object person

Tags: modeling, rigging, pose-mode

I'm having an issue I've tried fixing for literal weeks now. I've exhausted all the resources I could, but in short, I created an ultra low poly character that just WON'T rig right. I've attempted doing separate bones, and not using rigify, but ultimately, I imagine this will be a major pain when it comes to trying to do a walk cycle. In the picture, I've circled some areas I'm assuming are an issue, as I'm going with an icosphere for much of the joints (ankle, shoulder, elbow etc).

Am I doing something wrong, for why rigify is ineffective? Is using single bone setups like this feasible for movement and rudimentary animation?[image: image example]

Comment: Can you tell what kind of problems are you facing with the rig ?

Comment: For sure! This version is the single bone structure, which seems to move ok. But with rigify, everything below the waist doesn't work. Knee sockets are left in place, leg doesn't move with the rigify model etc. It's as if everything from the waist down basically doesnt exist, except for the feet, oddly enough. @Aster17

Comment: Hmmm... try not using rigify, it will work

Comment: To that point, is doing something like a walk cycle possible? Or using third party items like Mixamo? @aster17

Answer (score -1):

Using rigify will cause problems, especially if you have not cleared the scale. I would say as you have a character with many objects, go with making a rig and assigning each bone to each object. I have some very horrible experiences with rigify and going with bone by bone is much easier. As for if it is possible to do a walk cycle, yes it is highly possible.

Comment: Ok that is good to know. I guess my final question is, as far as parenting, and having a multi object character like this, is there a way to have it as a single layer? As it stands, upon selecting an item, say, the torso or arm, it is separate from the character. Is there a way to parent them so that upon clicking on, say, the leg, it selects the whole character? As it stands, it won't upload into mixamo. @aster17

Comment: Hmm... that won't work with blender. But, if you select the rig itself in object mode, and if you move the rig, the whole object will move as it is parented. But selecting one bone in pose mode or edit mode won't select the whole object though as it isn't possible in blender.